# Can nginx serve up files cached by PHP?

Tags: php, caching, nginx

As part of a new CMS that I'm planning, I'm going to be caching the HTML output of some "static" content. I say "static" because no content stored in a database is really static, but it's close enough. The system will MD5 hash the request URL and save a minified version of the HTML output in a cache folder. The next time the page is requested, the CMS will check if a cached version exists, then it'll check the age of the file and then serve up the cached version, thus saving a lot of resources (especially when it comes to DB calls).

Obviously getting nginx to serve up static files without going near PHP is going to be much quicker. So is there a way to get nginx to hash the request URL and check a temp folder to see if it exists?

Comment: I think you can do this in Nginx Conf - basically you use a get - loadUrl=get(md5).html - NGINX works with the major cache libraries already. Many CDN companies use it to do what you are doing - serving static content - you can even serve it compressed etc

Answer (score 1):

Yes!

You can get nginx to cache the response from the fcgi.  It is using the [HttpProxyModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule) that you must have enabled into nginx.

[Here](http://fennb.com/microcaching-speed-your-app-up-250x-with-no-n) is a good guide on how to do it.

Alternatively you can use nginx with memcache too.  There are actually quite a few options to you.  Both work really well!

Comment: Hi Lee. Microcaching looks like a great idea, but it says it wouldn't work for personalised content. This CMS will also be an eCommerce site, so obviously we can't serve up cached version of the cart! Nice idea though, might use that in some of my other projects.

Comment: You can always use memcache then to cache parts of the page that are not unique